# Using reduce to create new object but it updates old object

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm using reduce to take an array and return an object. The problem is it keeps updating the old object with the new key and value instead of making a new object.

```
let stateMap = newCopArray.reduce((stateMap, cop) => {
  

    
    let stateKey = cop.State;

    if (stateMap[stateKey] === undefined) {
        stateMap[stateKey] = 1;
    } else {
        stateMap[stateKey] += 1;
    }

   return stateMap

    
});
```

I want to return an object with a key for each US state in the original array with it's value being the amount of times it appears in the array.

Answer (score 3):

Pass an initial value `{}` to the `reduce()` as the second argument. And use different variable names.

```js
let stateMap = newCopArray.reduce((state, cop) => {
!state[cop.State] ? state[cop.State] = 1 : state[cop.State] += 1;
  return state;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to not override variables *(you use two `stateMap` variables)* and add initial value in reduce:

```
let stateMap = newCopArray.reduce((map, cop) => {
    let stateKey = cop.State;

    if (map[stateKey] === undefined) {
        map[stateKey] = 1;
    } else {
        map[stateKey] += 1;
    }

   return map;
}, {});
```